# F# Global.asax -- language not supported?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, f#, global-asax

Im trying to write a simple F# ASP.Net MVC app

Ive added the Global.asax as follows

```
<%@ Application Inherits="WebApplication.Core.Global" Language="F#" %>
```

then in a separate referenced assembly I have

```
namespace WebApplication.Core  with a type Global() = etc
```

Getting a 'F#' is not a supported language.

Am I not able to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add something like below in web.config:

```
<compiler language="F#;f#;fs;fsharp"
          extension=".fs"
          warningLevel="4"
          type="Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.FSharpAspNetCodeProvider,
            FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom, Version=1.9.6.2,
            Culture=neutral,
            PublicKeyToken=a19089b1c74d0809">
  <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5" />
  <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
</compiler>
```

Source and more details: http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2008/10/07/asp-net-mvc-with-nhaml-f-edition/

Comment: You can avoid having to do this by placing the class that implements your global.asax (a System.Web.HttpApplication) in an F# assembly and referencing this type in the "Inherits" attribute in global.asax. This is how the F# MVVM template works (available in visual studios online templates).

Comment: @Robert: can you post your comment as a new answer (and I will upvote it)?